# Configuring logging level in python

Tags: python

I have following log configuration file in python:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
handlers=screen,file

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=file,screen

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=complex
level=DEBUG
args=('spartacus.log',)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=complex
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

Run following python program:

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
logging.debug("1")
logging.info("2")
logging.warn("3")
logging.error("4")
logging.critical("5")
```

The output is:

```
[2014-04-01 11:25:04,720] WARNING [root.<module>:11] 3
[2014-04-01 11:25:04,720] ERROR [root.<module>:12] 4
[2014-04-01 11:25:04,720] CRITICAL [root.<module>:13] 5
```

Where are my INFO and DEBUG level log entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your root logger level to DEBUG:

```
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=screen,file
```

From the docs:

> Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING

Comment: Can you explain this? Why doesn't the level on the file handler have any effect?

Comment: The root logger dictates the base logging level which is inherited by child loggers and *may* be overridden by handlers; but it only takes effect if that level is *higher* than the logger it is associated with. So, for example, if the root level was DEBUG, but your screen handler had the level set to WARN, you would only see WARN or higher messages on your console.

Answer (score 0):

try this logging.conf file

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
handlers=screen,file
level=DEBUG

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=file,screen

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=complex
args=('spartacus.log',)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=complex
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

You need to set the level for logger.